# How to write a kafka consumer to consume a sqoop command?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have this sqoop command generated from a rest service and i want a kafka consumer to consume this sqoop command.

I am very new to kafka and need help with this.

Comment: Please provide more information: i.e. what have you tried? What messages are you receiving?

Comment: hi @QuintinBalsdon I have multiple sqoop commands coming from a rest interface. I would like to put all these sqoop commands into the kafka queue and consume it through a kafka queue at a different instance.